# Django Default Filter Question

Tags: django, filter

Im new to django and have two filter questions:

I have this code:

```
       {% for tip in tips %}
           <p>some text {{ tip }} some more text</p>
       {% endfor %}
```

My problem is that the output is:

> some text
>
> this is the tip
>
> some more text

Question #1)

How do I filter it (or disable the default filter for this) so it appears like this:

> some text this is the tip some more text

Question #2)

If the tip included

```
<b>Tip</b>
```

how would I get the text to be bold instead of printing the html markup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer 1)

```
<p>
{% for tip in tips %}
     some text {{ tip }} some more text
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

## Answer 2)

Mark the content of tip as safe by using `{{ tip|safe }}`. But Please be aware that this might be a security hole if the content of `tip` is somehow user supplied. It might lead to [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if someone could enter Javascript code intp tip.

Comment: Wow! I dont know how I missed the <p> tag! Staring at it too long. Thanks for the info on safe!